# Scala 2: Generic function that doubles a number

Tags: scala, generics

Multiplying x and 2 doesn't work. Scala version is 2.13.8.

```
import Integral.Implicits._
object hello {
  def f[T:Integral](x: T): T = x * 2
  val x: Int = 1
  f(x)
}
```

```
type mismatch;
  found : Int(2)
  required: T
    def f[T:Integral](x: T): T = x * 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what Levi mentioned, you'll need to import:

```
import scala.math.Integral.Implicits.infixIntegralOps
```

Still, you can simplify it to just:

```
def f[T: Integral](x: T): T = x * Integral[T].fromInt(2)
```

Taking advantage of the `Integral` companion object's `apply` method which takes an implicit of `Integral[T]` and returns it. It's exactly what `implicitly` does, only `implicitly` is more generic.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert `2` into a `T`.

Thankfully, the instance of the `Integral` typeclass for `T` (which is passed implicitly thanks to `[T: Integral]` has a `fromInt` method which can convert an `Int` like `2` into a `T`:

```scala
def f[T: Integral](x: T): T = {
  val two = implicitly[Integral[T]].fromInt(2)  // summons the typeclass instance
  x * two
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to convert the Int to a T?

Comment: Because all we know from it having an `Integral` instance is that we can call this method (with the right imports in scope): https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/math/Integral$IntegralOps.html#*(rhs:T):T, which requires that the right-hand-side of the `*` is a `T`